# drawable folders - What resolutions do I need

Tags: android, android-layout

All images I use in my app are located in one folder -> drawable-hdpi. I use them as backgrounds for my buttons, for my layouts and for some imageViews. These images have all different sizes from 50x50px to 900x900px.

I calculate the size of my buttons and other controls (in pixels) depending on the screen size (in pixels).

Pseudo-code:

```
 screenWidth = getScreenWidthInPixels();
 screenHeight = getScreenHeightInPixels();

 myButtons.setHeight(screenHeight * 0.1); //buttonHeight = 10 % of screenHeight
 ......
 ...
 ..
```

I want the quality of my images (button backgrounds, imageviews, layout backgrounds, ...) to be good on all devices.
There are now 5 different drawable folders. As far as I know I can now put the same images I already have in my drawable-hdpi folder in the other four drawable folders but with different resolutions.
What I'm trying to figuring out right now is what resolution I have to pick for what folder.  And like I said, my images have resolutions right now from 50x50px to 900x900px.

Comment: If you're only going to use a single set of images (which isn't a good idea because larger images will throw OutOfMemoryErrors on lower-end devices), then you should put them ALL in your drawable folder.

Comment: I don't want to use a single set. I want to have 5 sets of images and I want to android to pick the images from the right folder depending on the device. And then I work with that picked image like in my pseudo-code.

Comment: The "All images I use in my app are located in one folder -> drawable-hdpi." wording must have confused me.

Comment: Yup that's how it is currently. And this is what I want to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the resolutions in dpi:

```
ldpi:    120 dpi  
mdpi:    160 dpi  
hdpi:    240 dpi  
xhdpi:   320 dpi  
xxhdpi:  480 dpi  
xxxhdpi: 640 dpi
```

You have to calculate the dimensions in pixels basing on the resulution:

Scale factor:

```
ldpi:    0.75  
mdpi:    1.0  
hdpi:    1.5  
xhdpi:   2.0  
xxhdpi:  3.0  
xxxhdpi: 4.0
```

You COULD have all the images in the xxxhdpi folder and let Android scale them down... but not always you'd get nice results (Android scaling **DOWN** is good, but not as good as pre-sized images).
Nowadays I guess that an xxhdpi resolution is enough, but tomorrow...
It would be scaled **UP** on an xxxhdpi screen, with not-so-good results (visible pixellation).

A solution would be using svg graphics (which is a vectorial standard based on xml), but you'd need an external library (there are several open source / free - you choose the one which fits best) to render them in a standard control.

Comment: So if my image has a resolution of 50 x 100 px in mdpi it is supposed to have a resolution of 75 x 150 px in hdpi ?

Comment: Yes, correct. The scale factor rules. You see, you COULD have all the images in the xxxhdpi folder and let Android scale them down... but not always you'd get nice results (Android scaling **DOWN** is good, but not as good as pre-sized images). Nowadays I guess that an xxhdpi resolution is enough, but tomorrow... It would be scaled **UP** on an xxxhdpi screen, with horrible results (visible pixellation)

Answer (score 0):

if you have an icom with 100*100 px in the mdpi then :

(3:4:6:8)

mdpi  (4)  = 100*100 px (default image)

hdpi  (6)  = (100*6)/4  = 150*150 px

xhdpi (8)  = (100*8)/4 = 200*200 px or (150*8)/6 = 200*200

Comment: Or, better: `hdpi = mdpi * 1.5`, `xhdpi = mdpi * 2` ;)

Comment: This is a standard approach. for example : calculate ic_launcher in the mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi : 48 - 72 - 96

Comment: Yes, correct, but you do some more calculations than really needed (you multiply ten divide). I do less calculations to get the SAME RESULTS (I only multiply by the density scale factor).