# Do i will have to make different values and layout folder for Android App Bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-app-bundle

I am at final stage of my app and I am thinking to use App bundle to publish my app. So my question do i will have to make separate values and layout folder too? Like values folder for English

Or I can continue without any making extra layout and values folder for different sizes like Hdpi , XHdpi and for values, values-EN etc.. because I have not made extra folders for these

Answer (score 1):

For drawables, you don't create extra folders under layout files. The folders should be under drawables directory, clearly representing the different image resolutions...ie `LDPI`, `MDPI`, `HDPI`, `XHDPI`, `XXHDPI`, `XXXHDPI`

For your case, you don't need the values-EN folder.

A similar question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567444/16698687)